# Passing multiple values for a single variable between 2 pages in php

Tags: php, session, web

I m developing a php site for mobile phones. It's home page has images of several phones, all are having a unique Id.(1,2,3,...).So when I click on an Image a the page should be redirected to another page(Details.php) and display images and information related to the image that I just clicked. I tried doing this using a session variable but if so I'll have to use separate session variable to each phone. How can I solve this issue. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you simply use GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a GET variable to pass those information.

index.php or whatever where the phones are listed

```
<a href="details.php?phoneid=1"><img src="phone01.jpg"></a>
<a href="details.php?phoneid=2"><img src="phone02.jpg"></a>
<a href="details.php?phoneid=3"><img src="phone03.jpg"></a>
```

And at the details.php. You can use this

```
if(isset($_GET['phoneid'])) {
    $phoneid = $_GET['phoneid'];
    switch ($phoneid) {
        case '1':
            echo 'Phone 1';
            break;
        case '2':
            echo 'Phone 2';
            break;
        case '3':
            echo 'Phone 3';
            break;
    }
} else {
    // no value of phoneid
}
```

Another easier way is to use mySQL to list all the phones.

Comment: This is working but I need to pass the phoneId conbcatenated with a php script. When I just pass ?phoneid=1 , it's working perfectly. But I can't use it this way. <a href="Details.php?phoneid=<?php $Pid_arr[count($Pid_arr)-1]?> " class="product" title="Product 1">'      Can you please explain me why?

Comment: You mean like you want to pass it like a POST variable?

Answer (score 2):

In `details.php` you could add code similar to `$phoneId = $_GET["id"]` and append `?id=#` (where `#` is the phone's ID) to the end of each link.

### Example

Listing the phones, this assumes you have an array `$phones` with the data

```
foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    echo "<a href='details.php?id=" . $phone["id"] . "'><img src='images/phone" . $phone["id"] . ".png'></a>";
}
```

Determine which phone the user selected (in `details.php`), also assuming you have a `$phones` array

```
// Check if an ID was sent
if (empty($_GET["id"])) {
    // The user didn't select a phone
} else {
    // Get the phone ID
    $phoneID = $_GET["id"];

    // Check if the ID is valid
    if (array_key_exists($phoneID, $phones)) {
        // Select the phone
        $phone = $phones[$phoneID];
    } else {
        // The ID is invalid
    }
}
```